# Remove the Internal columns in a NODE/EDGE table in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssms

I'm using a graph DB in SSMS (19.0.2) and I would like to plot it using Power BI.

As seen in a video I must create a VIEW to obtain the columns that I need for Power BI and I have to remove the not $ columns (`graph_id`, etc.). Now here I have the problem.

If I create the view and select the columns that I need (for example: `$node_id`, `$edge_id`, `$from_id`, `$to_id`) I have also the `graph_id` column (not $ columns) in the view's columns, and I don't want them.

How can I resolve this problem? Because Power BI doesn't accept the Internal columns of the edge/node tables.

I tried to create the view but I have the internal columns inside it. I don't know how to do.

Comment: please attach the view code

Comment: Why can't you just remove that column from the view definition?

Comment: I resolve the problem, at the end I created a new normal table and I insert into it the data that i need.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE VIEW myView AS
SELECT $node_id, $edge_id, $from_id, $to_id
FROM myGraphTable
```

you can use `SELECT` with "$" as prefix to select only the columns that you need

```
CREATE VIEW myView AS
SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM myGraphTable
WHERE column1 NOT LIKE 'not %' AND column2 NOT LIKE 'not %'
```

you can also explicitly exclude non-$ columns by specifying the column names in `SELECT` + using `"NOT LIKE"` to exclude non-$ columns

once view with only $-prefixed columns | excluded non-$ columns -- you should be able to use it in Power BI without any issues